# I want to send a mail through lotus notes and the receiver should not get to see who send the mail

Tags: lotus-notes

I want to send a mail through lotus notes and the receiver should not get to see who send the mail. Instead, the receiver should be getting the sender name as my organization name.

Comment: Ask you organization IT department to set up a generic account like info@yourorganization.com and send an email from it. This is common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Team Mailbox template on OpenNTF which provides the functionality to be able to respond with a team/group email address instead of your own email address: https://teammail.openntf.org/